# ASP.NET File Monitoring errors in Event Log

Tags: asp.net

We are getting frequent errors in the Event Viewer, Application section. The source is ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0, category is File Monitoring. The Event ID is 1185. Text says "Failed to start monitoring changes to "file-path-here" because the network BIOS command limit has been reached." Then there is a reference to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886.

The question is: what process or service is doing this file monitoring, and why? We are not aware of how this is running or how it started. The monitoring seems to look at various folders on our web site, some are .NET folders, some are not.

We are looking for explanation of what is causing this monitoring; then we will try to address the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monitoring is being done by IIS (or the aspnet process with IIS6). It's watching for changes to files so that the site can be recompiled when needed.

You didn't mention your environment, but I used to run into this problem frequently when trying to run websites from Windows XP when the sites were located on a remote file share. I think the error comes up due to a limitation in CIFS (the network stack for file shares). Windows Server didn't seem to have the same limitations.

So, a few possible fixes:

1. Switch to Windows Server (or possibly Win 7)
2. Switch to a Web Application (doesn't allow recompiles)
3. Move your files from a remote share to a local drive

Comment: Your answer got me pointed in the right direction. Here is more information:  Site runs on Windows Server 2003.  1,500 folders, 40,000 files,  2,000 classic ASP files,  20 ASP.NET files.  All files are stored on a SAN.  This fits the diagnosis you mentioned. Therefore it seems that ASP.NET is monitoring a very large number of folders and files to detect changes in a small number of places. In other words, it is overmonitoring. Do you know of any way to restrict the monitoring to only those folders that contain ASP.NET code? I have searched for doc on this process but haven't found any.

Comment: There are plenty of sites out there with many more files than yours (one of my sites has about 500K files), so I doubt file count alone is the issue. Are you accessing the SAN over a network shared drive? I don't think IIS gives you any control over which files are monitored. As an experiment, you might try splitting the site into two sites, with active content in one, and static in another.

Answer (score 1):

When a asp.net starts to run a site, is monitoring one basic file (on the root of the web site), this is the `app_offline.htm` and if he finds it is stop the program showing only this file.

If find that other file change is recompile them if this is nessesary, but still showing the app_offline.htm if exist and not run the site.

Ones you remove the app_offline.htm the web pages starts run again, but asp.net still monitoring for this file - if exist or not.

So this is the monitoring of the asp.net you search for. Of course this is the default behaviour of asp.net. If you have install other software or something else have been on computer and fill it with monitoring, this is something different. I assume that you have too many web sites asp.net on the same server ? 500 or more ? if not then maybe you start searching for other software that make this monitoring of your files.

### Analysis

How to find your self whats happends, download the Handle from sysinternals and run it, make the out on a text file like `handle.exe >> result.txt` and look the results.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Look there if any suspicious program have open huge amount of files and what program is that. Monitoring files and directories are shown like

```
runningprogram.exe pid: 1352 ServerName\User
       AC: File  (RW-)   D:\Monitor1
       E8: File  (RW-)   D:\Monitor2
       F8: File  (RW-)   D:\Monitor3
      408: File  (RWD)   D:\InetPub\MySite
```

### More

I check on my servers and found that a blog creation program have add a monitoring on every directory blog - I do not know why - but this is the way they have made it, to monitoring every blog for some reason, maybe you have something similar that creates a lot of file/directory monitoring for some reason.